# What is the Webhook Event "Payment order" | Shopify | Webhook | Node.js

Tags: node.js, shopify, webhooks, shopify-app

I want to create a Webhook that listens to order/paid in Shopify. But when I go to the create a web hook panel, there isn't a event with orders/paid.

The only relevant webhooks are "order was updated" or "Payment order". My purpose is to send out an email, when we mark a order as paid. What webhook should I create?

Here is a screenshot of the Webhook Panel (but in German):

(Hint: "Zahlungsauftrag" means "Payment order")

[image: Here is the screenshot of the create Webhook Panel (but in German :) )]

Maybe someone can help me out.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see from the image, order creation web hook will listen the paid order of each customer.

```
app.post('/api/order/created', (req, res) => {
    // let Shopify know we received the order details ok

    // the body of the data received
    const theData = req.body;
    console.log(theData);
    res.send('OK');
  });
```

[image]

I wish this might help you.
Thanks.

Comment: That wasn't my question. My question was what "Payment order" Webhook does?